# How to add a condition to a specific time to a bar

Tags: pine-script

how can I adjust the code below to only highlight the bar if the condition are met with consider to the time?

//@version=5
indicator("", "", true)

bgcolor(dayofweek==5 and time==1400 and close > 1 ? color.new(color.green, 40):na)

If I remove time it works like a charm

bgcolor(dayofweek==5 and close > 1 ? color.new(color.green, 40):na)

Answer (score 1):

```
t1 = time(timeframe.period, "0930-1400:23456")
bgcolor(t1 ? color.new(color.blue, 90) : na)
```

Used above for condiiton in IST 09:30am to 3:00 pm,
The graph is as shown in image

[image]

While setting up a session you can specify not just the hours and minutes but also the days of the week that will be included in that session.

If the days aren't specified, the session is considered to have been set from Sunday (1) to Saturday (7), i.e. "1100-2000" is the same as "1100-1200:1234567".

You can change that by specifying the days. For example, on a symbol that is traded seven days a week with the 24-hour trading session the following script will not color Saturdays and Sundays:

Answer (score 0):

Hey CC from TV here and the reason why is because time is a timestamp and the way pinescript is coded, it won't ever equal that amount but an easy workaround would be the following (tested and it works)

```
bgcolor(dayofweek == 5 and time >= 1400 and close > 1 ? color.new(color.green, 40) : na)
```

EDIT: To address your original question and your comment, here is another way to write it:

```
bgcolor(dayofweek == 5 and time(timeframe.period, "1400-1400:23456") and close > 1 ? color.new(color.green, 40) : na)
```

Comment: Thanks, it now color the whole day (the same is if I exclude time), my intention is to only cover the given hour if the other condition are met, is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: Found an solution
   //@version=5
indicator("Time", overlay=true)
t1 = time(timeframe.period, "0000-0100:23456")
bgcolor(t1 ? color.new(color.blue, 90) : na)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your response in time

Comment: I posted an update but your solution would only highlight times from midnight to 1am eastern standard time so that is why I edited my answer to show what you were looking for